# Can't install support for ECW in QGIS 3.6 / 3.4 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: qgis, gdal, ubuntu, ecw

I've been trying to install support for **ECW** so I can load them in latest QGIS 3.6 (also tried in QGIS 3.4.4)

Having tried the following tutorials:

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/ECW   (**gdal 2.2.3**)

https://gist.github.com/1papaya/568c4580b1909071696c1cb119101823   (**gdal 2.3.1**)

Both appear to work and report back ECW support against gdal

> **gdalinfo --formats | grep ECW**
>   ECW -raster- (rw): ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (SDK 3.x)
>   JP2ECW -raster,vector- (rw+v): ERDAS JPEG2000 (SDK 3.x)

However when opening **QGIS** I notice that key UI is missing - the little triangles next to all the processing toolbox processes are missing, and the whole of QGIS becomes unstable - for example it crashes to desktop when selecting plugins within the plugin manager.

[image]

I then have alot of trouble recovering QGIS to get the UI back - full removal and purge of all dependencies + QGIS reinstall does not restore it! have to carry out full ubuntu reinstall to get it all back, which is not ideal.

Is gdal completely independent per version install. as above tutorials focus on particular gdal download which you then appear to manipulate?

**QGIS 3.6** appears to use **gdal 2.2.3**

**QGIS 3.4.4** appears to use **gdal 2.4.0**

so far I've carried out above tutorials first then installed QGIS, should I perhaps install QGIS first then attempt to adjust the GDAL that QGIS installs as a dependency?

Comment: Hi,I have this issue too in Ubuntu 22.04 and QGIS 3.32 and QGIS 3.28 ,Did you find out what should we do?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use a self-compiled GDAL with QGIS packages, you have to use exactly the same GDAL version that the packages are compiled against. For bionic (Ubuntu 18.04 and Linux Mint 19), You can find the version in https://qgis.org/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Packages and https://qgis.org/ubuntugis/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Packages if you search for the `gdal-abi` dependency.

Currently this is GDAL 2.2.3 in the main Ubuntu repo and 2.3.2 in the Ubuntugis-unstable ppa.

https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ECW suggests to use the ECW SDK v 5.4 with GDAL 2.2.4 or newer.

**UPDATE FROM THE COMMENTS**

It seems to be necessary to install the `libpng-dev` package **before** self-compiling GDAL.

Don't remove the packaged GDAL version, because this will remove QGIS and any other GDAL-dependant package too. Instead, copy the self-compiled libgdal files and the libNCSEcw files from `/usr/local/lib` to `/usr/lib`.

QGIS 2.18.28 from the ubuntugis unstable ppa (without using any qgis.org) installs fine along with the ECW driver, as well as QGIS 3.4 and QGIS 3.6 from `https://qgis.org/ubuntugis-ltr bionic` or `https://qgis.org/ubuntugis bionic`. It even works for GDAL 2.2.3 and Qgis 3.6 from `https://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic` without any ubuntugis dependency.

If you installed against ubuntugis-unstable, You have to update and recompile GDAL every time that ubuntugis-unstable updates GDAL. The GDAL version in the main ubuntu repo will not change, until you upgrade your OS to a newer version.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this AndreJ, I've just tested both of these in my sources.list  
https://qgis.org/ubuntugis-ltr bionic  &
https://qgis.org/ubuntugis bionic  

and get the following trying to install via this command  
**sudo aptitude -f install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass**


The following packages have unmet dependencies:

**libqgis-analysis3.4.5 : Depends: gdal-abi-2-3-0 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package  

libqgis-app3.4.5 : Depends: libproj13 (>= 5.0.0) which is a..**  

Amongst a couple of others dependency issues.

Comment: You should only select one of them, and add the ubuntugis-unstable ppa too, see https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable/ . Then update and upgrade to get the latest updates. This should bring you GDAL 2.3.2 (without ECW). Check that you have the necessary keys for ubuntugis and QGIS, otherwise you can't update. After that, you can install qgis and python-qgis.

Comment: indeed I was testing each deb independently, but only after adding the PPA you noted above did I get past the GDAL dependency errors. So I've now got QGIS 3.4.5 and GDAL 2.3.2 - would I now need to simply follow - https://gist.github.com/1papaya/568c4580b1909071696c1cb119101823  to rebuild GDAL?

Comment: Yes, but don't remove the GDAL package, it would remove QGIS too. Instead, just recompile, and copy the files from `/usr/local/lib` to `/usr/lib`. And take GDAL 2.3.2.

Comment: ok so after following steps in the github tutorial, my folder **/usr/local/lib** contained 5 GDAL related files which I then copied to **/usr/lib** using **sudo find -iname 'libgdal*' -exec cp {} /usr/lib/ \;**  it overwrote 2 existing GDAL files already within **/usr/lib**  'libgdal.so.20' & 'libgdal.so.20.4.2'.  But starting up QGIS and I'm getting the exact same corruption as per my first post - very unstable broken UI, and crashing frequently. This was with QGIS 3.6 and GDAL 2.3.2. QGIS was fine just prior to the copying of files. Am I doing the copy incorrectly?

Comment: Spotted following comment on [This Post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209179/how-to-get-ecw-support-on-qgis-2-16-ubuntu-16-04)
"because of QGIS installs library in /usr/lib but your compiled library will be here /usr/local/lib, you have to do backup the n.3 files in /usr/lib starting with libgdal.so* and then create a soft link to those with the same name in /usr/local/lib. Restart QGIS and it will work."  so I assume a simple 'copy' is not appropriate.

Comment: I had that trouble too, and downgraded to QGIS 2.18.28 from the ubuntugis ppa (without any files from qgis.org). After that worked with ECW, I updated to QGIS 3.4.4 from qgis.org/ubuntugis-ltr, then to QGIS 3.6 from qgis.org/ubuntugis. I'm not sure why it works since then. Maybe you have still some packages from qgis.org/ubtuntu installed.

Comment: Well that's a mighty awkward process! - installing QGIS 3 times. So I also tried symbolic links from **usr/local/lib** after backing up originals in **usr/lib** and still no joy - same exact issue in QGIS.
Get this error when trying to run qgis from terminal: 
**libpng error: Incompatible libpng version in application and library
libpng warning: Application was compiled with png.h from libpng-1.6.34
libpng warning: Application  is  running with png.c from libpng-1.2.56**

Comment: Maybe related: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19562 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291191/libpng-problems-for-qgis and https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2013-August/036903.html

Comment: ... and https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2017-November/047697.html . I guess libpng-dev is missing.

Comment: ok I found a guaranteed fix without having to install QGIS multiple times. Turns out that indeed it was **libpng-dev** that needed to be installed before carrying out the recompile of GDAL The last answer in the [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291191/libpng-problems-for-qgis) AndreJ noted above clarified it for me. So on Ubuntu 18.04, I can now load ECW rasters into QGIS 3.6 with GDAL 2.3.2. 
I also have to temporarily run **export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib**. But I might attempt to return to symbolic links to see if I can get that working again.

Comment: Forked version of first tutorial I followed - https://gist.github.com/rossoe/460365ed47975a11e11bcd6084064f28

Comment: I just did a quick test on another system without any ubuntugis. Installing libpng-dev and self-compiling GDAL 2.2.3 gives ECW support for QGIS 3.6.0 as well.

Comment: Hi,I have this issue too in Ubuntu 22.04 and QGIS 3.32 and QGIS 3.28 , your solution didnt work for me.could you please help me.