# ECW errors on ubuntugis

Tags: qgis, openlayers, openstreetmap, qgis-processing

i have successfully installed the ECW support on ubuntu qgis. the main challenge that i have is that whenever i try and load an ecw file, the qgis main window crashes. On the other had i am able to succesfully load all my vector layers with ease. any suggestions?

Comment: ECW is a raster format, you need to load it as a raster layer not vector layer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECW_(file_format)

Comment: As a follow-up of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313294/cant-install-support-for-ecw-in-qgis-3-6-3-4-on-ubuntu-18-04/313388#313388 : Did you install the libpng-dev package before self-compiling GDAL? I had the same crashes before I did.