# Opening ECW and EWW files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, ecw

For my project I need to bring ECW and eww files into QGIS (3.10 Coruna). The aerial pictures of the ECW files give no problems and are well georeferenced. However, I cannot open the EWW raster files in QGIS, which indicate which areas of the ecw files are treated. The error I get is: "Invalid Layer: GDAL provider Cannot open GDAL dataset C". Is there something I can do to fix this or another program I can use? I just need to see which parts are treated, no further processing or calculations will be required. I tried ERDAS ER mapper and IAR EW for arm, but the first one didn't work because of issues with a license and the latter gave problems as well.

Comment: I would assume the EWW files are the world files for ECW files.  If so they would only be a few kb in size and you could open them in notepad or other text editor and see georeferencing coordinates and related into.

Answer (score 1):

1. Reinstall QGIS with the OSGeo4W installer.
2. Select `Advanced Install`

[image]

3. Click next until you get to package selection.
4. Expand `Libs` and enable `gdal-ecw`

[image]

5. Continue to approve the licences, note that it only enables reading ECW, not writing.
6. Finish the install and open your files in QGIS.

Comment: This works for Windows. For Linux see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313294/cant-install-support-for-ecw-in-qgis-3-6-3-4-on-ubuntu-18-04/313388#313388