# Installing QGIS with ECW support on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: qgis, gdal, ubuntu, ecw

I know there are similar questions here, but I've tried every answer and every tutorial I could find, and I still can't open ECW with QGIS (and I kind of broke my qgis install? When I try to install QGIS I have dependancy errors for qgis-providers, qgis-plugin-grass and python-qgis now). I use Ubuntu 20.04 and QGIS 3.24.1.

I compiled GDAL with ECW support, which seems to work fine as
`gdalinfo --formats | grep ECW` gives

```
ECW -raster- (rw+): ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (SDK 5.4)
JP2ECW -raster,vector- (rw+v): ERDAS JPEG2000 (SDK 5.4)
```

But I don't know how to make QGIS use the version that I compiled. `gdalinfo --version` gives me `GDAL 2.3.2, released 2018/09/21` but when I go to the QGIS details it says QGIS is using GDAL 3.0.4. I also tried one of the tutorials from a clean Ubuntu install (on a virtual box) and it still didn't work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I'm not really used to dealing with these kinds of things so potentially I *am* doing some things wrong. I also read somewhere that I should try to compile QGIS with my GDAL install but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Latest QGIS versions use GDAL 3, so I think you need to compile GDAL 3 with ECW first in order to use it with QGIS.

Comment: omg thanks I didn't actually except it to work but it did ??? Thank you ! @J.Monticolo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from comments and [Can't install support for ECW in QGIS 3.6 / 3.4 on Ubuntu 18.04](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313294/cant-install-support-for-ecw-in-qgis-3-6-3-4-on-ubuntu-18-04?rq=1):

You have to compile **the same GDAL version** used by QGIS with ECW support manually to use ECW inside QGIS.

Comment: Hi, how find out which version to use I don't know which version of GDAL is used in `ECWJP2SDKSetup_5.5.0.2268-Update4-Linux` and QGIS 3.22.4.

Answer (score 8):

#### Compiling GDAL using proprietary library to support ECW file format - Ubuntu

#### QGIS uses GDAL for file formats.

###### 1. UPDATE -

- Download zip file from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EZnwRzDgbYd_kTiDqigmJbON5REDha5s/view?usp=sharing) for 5.4.0
- Downlaod the latest version from hexagon [site](https://supportsi.hexagon.com/s/article/ERDAS-ECW-JP2-SDK-Read-Only-Redistributable-download)

```
unzip ERDAS_ECWJP2_SDK-5.4.0.bin.zip
chmod +x ./ERDAS_ECWJP2_SDK-5.4.0.bin
```

###### 2. Run bin - Choose Option 1. Desktop_Read-Only

`./ERDAS_ECWJP2_SDK-5.4.0.bin`

###### 3. Copy installed files to /usr/local/hexagon_ecw

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/hexagon_ecw
sudo cp -r hexagon/ERDAS-ECW_JPEG_2000_SDK-5.4.0/Desktop_Read-Only/* /usr/local/hexagon_ecw
```

###### 4. Make symbolic link to libs like libNCSEcw.so.**

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/hexagon_ecw/lib/x64/release/* /usr/local/lib/
```

###### 5. Download and install proper PROJ version

Get PROJ version from Help->About Mine is 6.3.1

Download from https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/releases.

```
tar -xvf proj-6.3.1.tar.gz
cd proj-6.3.1
mkdir build 
cd build
cmake .. # had to install libsqlite3-dev dependency
make -j$(nproc)
sudo make install
```

###### 6. Downlad GDAL for specific QGIS version

Get GDAL version from Help->About QGIS 3.26.3 uses gdal 3.0.4

Download from http://download.osgeo.org/gdal

```
tar -xvzf gdal-3.0.4.tar.gz
cd gdal-3.0.4
./configure --with-ecw=/usr/local/hexagon_ecw
make -j$(nproc) # Compile takes a lot of time... 
sudo make install
```

If you get errors on `make` above, use this bellow before the make command above (from [here](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/2657))

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=//usr/local/hexagon_ecw/lib/cpp11abi/x64/release:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

###### 7. Set env. variables

```
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib' >> ~/.profile
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib' >> ~/.bashrc
GDAL_DATA="/usr/local/share/gdal"
ldconfig
```

###### 8. Check if ECW is installed

`gdalinfo --formats | grep ECW`

Based and updated from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/QGIS/comments/icw98f/problem_loading_ecw_file_in_ubuntu_linux/).

Tested on Ubuntu 22.04 and 20.04

Comment: In my case, cmake .. comand finish with sqlite3, libtiff and curl libraries not found errors.
So I have to do: sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev libtiff-dev  libcurl4-openssl-dev

Comment: Then  "./configure --with-ecw=/usr/local/Desktop_Read-Only" finish with "error: PROJ 6 symbols not found" so need to do sudo apt-get install libproj-dev

Comment: Hi, I did the same as you said but it didn't work for me.`gdalinfo --formats | grep ECW ` shows nothing and I can't open ECW Map inside QGIS.

Comment: @imbr thanks for your response, I wonder that I have no problem in QGIS in windows but in Linux they didn't support ECW and they didn't provide any solution. I will be appreciated if tell me too as soon as find it.

Comment: @Parisa.H.R just found in my e-mail one old answer of them with the new link after you create a account on their support portal (free). Updated above!

Comment: Newer gdal releases no longer ship with `./configure` so the above instructions aren't working (tested with gdal 3.7.0), and I can't find a download link for the 5.4.0 ERDAS ECW JP2 SDK (only 5.5.0 is available at the linked download page)

Answer (score 0):

I went through these useful instructions, installing gdal 3.4.1 with proj (> v6), and the most current version of the ecw driver (ECWJP2SDKSetup_5.5.0.2268-Update4-Linux)... I'm running Ubuntu 22.04. AFter it's finished installing, gdal 3.4.1 is working, although I still don't have ECW support. However, I'm pretty sure my installation of the ECW Driver was ok. I didn't see any obvious error in my gdal build related to the ECW library, and the various library files now appear in /usr/local/lib... weird.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).