# How open ECW Maps in QGIS 3.22

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, ecw

I want to load ECW maps in QGIS 3.22 In ubuntu 22.04
I ran the latest version (master repo) of the code with Qt 5.15 and also tried it by installing it ( QGIS 3.22.4-Białowieża)
In both ways, I can't load `.ecw maps`

I also tried StackOverflow questions said like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/27247/200592) or [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/bogind/libecwj2-3.3) but the problem is that these ways are too old and they didn't work.

> Invalid Data Source:
> /home/parisa/Downloads/apps/BlueMarble/ttMaps/Maps/BlueMarble/01.ecw
> is not a valid or recognized data source.

[image]

[image]

#### Versions

QGIS 3.22.4-Białowieża

and

QGIS 3.28 and the latest version under development (master branch)

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/429214/installing-qgis-with-ecw-support-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: @Mapperz  thanks for your comment but the problem is that https://download.hexagongeospatial.com/downloads/ecw/erdas-ecw-jp2-sdk-v5-4-linux show me nothing.I can't download it

Comment: https://supportsi.hexagon.com/help/s/licensingportal now requires a login/subscription

Comment: @Mapperz Hi, I did the same as your link said but it didn't work for me.`gdalinfo --formats | grep ECW ` shows nothing and I can't open ECW Map inside QGIS. I get `ECWJP2SDKSetup_5.5.0.2268-Update4-Linux` because I didn't find 5.4.0 and `gdal-3.4.1` . But I cant understand why QGIS didn't support this in Linux versions.I have no problem in Windows and I can see ECW Maps without need to install other things. Please help me I don't know what should I do.